# QListWidget deleting QListWidgetItem causes segmentaion fault

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a C++ application where I am reading `pcap` file format and processing usb packets. For each packet, I would like to create a `QListWidgetItem` to which I am storing some data and then adding it to the `QListWidget`. Here is where the trouble begins. According to QListWidget documentation, after inserting item :

> The list widget will take ownership of the item.

So what I thought is that its on `QListWidget` to delete all `QListWidgetItems`. The items are added fine, but when I close my app(I suppose thats when desctructor od `QListWidget` is called so he is calling desctructor of each `QListWidgetItem`) I get `delete_scalar exception`. According to call stack, deletion of some QListWidgetItem triggers it :[image: call stack screen]

Snippet of my code (this function is being called for each packet in pcap file and is responsible for creating and adding items):

```cpp
 void ItemManager::ProcessPacket(QByteArray packetData)
    {
        const unsigned char* packet = (unsigned char*)packetData.data();
        PUSBPCAP_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER usbh = (PUSBPCAP_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER)packet;
    
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem;
    
        //set USBPCAP header to item
        QByteArray usbhArray((const char*)packet, sizeof(USBPCAP_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER));
        item->setData(dataHolder->USBPCAP_HEADER_DATA, QVariant(usbhArray));
        packet += sizeof(USBPCAP_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER);
    
        if (usbh->transfer == USBPCAP_TRANSFER_ISOCHRONOUS || usbh->transfer == USBPCAP_TRANSFER_CONTROL) //check for optional header data
        {
            int additionalDataSize = usbh->headerLen - sizeof(USBPCAP_BUFFER_PACKET_HEADER);
            if (additionalDataSize > 0)
            {
                //set additional header data to item
                QByteArray additionalDataArray((const char*)(packet), additionalDataSize);
                item->setData(dataHolder->TRANSFER_OPTIONAL_HEADER, QVariant(additionalDataArray));
                packet += additionalDataSize;
            }
            else
            {
                item->setData(dataHolder->TRANSFER_OPTIONAL_HEADER, QVariant()); //QVariant creates invalid QVariant, later i just need to check with QVariant::isValid()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            item->setData(dataHolder->TRANSFER_OPTIONAL_HEADER, QVariant());
        }
    
        //set leftover data to item
        QByteArray leftoverDataArray((const char*)packet, usbh->dataLength);
        item->setData(dataHolder->TRANSFER_LEFTOVER_DATA, QVariant(leftoverDataArray));
    
        listWidget->insertItem(listWidget->count(), item);
    }
```

Calling of `ProcessPacket` function :

```cpp
void ItemManager::ProcessFile(QString filename, bool liveReading)
{
    if (fileReader.OpenNewFile(filename))
    {
        if (fileReader.ReadFileHeader())
        {
            while (!stopButtonClicked)
            {
                while (!fileReader.EndOfFile())
                {
                    QByteArray packetData = fileReader.GetPacket();
                    if (!pauseButtonClicked)
                    {
                        ProcessPacket(packetData);
                    }
                }

                parent->Refresh();  //this is just calling QCoreApplication::processEvents();

                if (!atBottomOfList)
                {
                    listWidget->scrollToBottom();
                }

                if (liveReading)
                {
                    Sleep(50);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I found out that this problem is happening only when appending to `QListWidget` through `ItemManager` class. In my main Q_OBJECT class `USB_Packet_Analyzer`(which holds `QlistWidget` that I am appending to) i have slot `on_OpenButton_clicked()` which looks like this :

```cpp
void USB_Packet_Analyzer::on_OpenButton_clicked()
{
    QString fil = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Select source file", ".", "Pcap files (*.pcap)");
    ItemManager manager(ui.listWidget,this);
    manager.ProcessFile(fil, ui.liveCaptureRadioButton->isChecked());
}
```

where in `ItemManager` class constructor looks like this :

```cpp
ItemManager::ItemManager(QListWidget* listWidget, USB_Packet_Analyzer* parent)
{
    this->stopButtonClicked = false;
    this->pauseButtonClicked = false;
    this->atBottomOfList = false;
    this->listWidget = listWidget;
    this->parent = parent;
    this->dataHolder = DataHolder::GetDataHolder();
}
```

Now, if I add items in `on_OpenButton_clicked()` slot and close the app, everything is fine. But when I create `ItemManager` instance and append items in that class, the error occurs. Could it be that I am not allowed to pass `QListWidget*` as parameter ?

Comment: Looks like deletion of the already freed memory. You might want to check, where you explicitly delete a Qt object which is a child of another Qt object.

Comment: @vahancho what Qt objects do you mean ? I have only 1 Q_OBJECT class which i got when I created Qt app. This class has ownership of `QListWidget`. For adding `QListWidgetItems` I have another class `ItemManager` which is responsible for reading `pcap` files and adding items(it has pointer to `QListWidgetItem` for adding purposes). `ItemManager` class is being destroyed after finished reading file, but my main Q_OBJECT class is still alive. I suppose it is being deleted after closing app main window just before the program ends.

Comment: Pretty sure that the problematic code is not shown - everything seems fine in what you have posted so far. My suspicion is that you have some other code that is deleting the `QListWidget` or `USB_Packet_Analyzer` and then Qt tries to delete it again. Are your storing any `QObject` derived classes in smart pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this day I am not completely sure what caused the error, but it was fixed after I modified `USBPCAP` structs which I were using. They use all kind of stuff like `#pragma pack(1) , #pragma pack(push)` and so on. It looks like I was missing some of those, which might result in some undefined behaviour while using them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new item inside your loop. You must not reuse the pointer because no content is copied, only the pointer is stored within the QListWidget

Comment: I am not sure if i understood your answer correctly, but I dont think I am reusing the same pointer. I edited my question so there is also a loop of calling `ProcessPacket` function.

Comment: You're right - I saw a loop in your code before. Are you sure you don't delete the item(s) anywhere else?

Comment: Yes, this is the only place where I am working with `QListWidget` and appending items to it. I even tried to cut whole `ProcessPacket` function and just create empty `QListWidgetItem` in `while (!fileReader.EndOfFile())` loop and append it to `QlistWidget` and ended up with the same result.

Comment: Then please create a minimal, reproducible example.